# Is an edit removing a keyword from title because it's a tag acceptable?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, title

Consider the edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10753302). It removed the keyword **C#** from the title because it's already mentioned as a tag. Should this edit be approved? And generally, is it better to mention the scope of the question in its title or just add it as a tag?

Comment: I like seeing the scope in the title. Tags don't tell the whole story, and sometimes the title can be hard to understand with parts missing. Also, some questions have many tags.

Comment: meta.se dupe: [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190)

Comment: The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) gives question titles that just slap tags at the beginning or end as an example of what not to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have rejected that edit, because while removing tags forced into the title is a good thing, removing it here doesn't make the title much better, nor does the suggester address any other of the glaring deficiencies of that post.

I made a proper edit myself now, though it's probably wasted effort:
It's properly on it's way to being closed as unclear or no MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't sure: skip.

Do you find another improvement that should be done: reject and edit.

You don't find another improvement that should be done: approve.

Comment: The last sentence should read: "You looked hard and don't find another improvement..." :p

Comment: @honk noted....